# Python - How to get final URL and data with redirect

Tags: python, redirect, python-requests

I tried to connect a link which has status code `200`, but I got the following message:

```
print _r.text
<script>window.location.href='/'</script>
```

When I try connecting to this link again, I still get this message again!!

**How to get the final url and data?**

Full Code:

```
__u = 'https://www.jobui.com/process/'
__h = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36',}
__data = {
        'ormAction: company_review_changeCommentPage'
        'companyID': '10954743',
        'commentID': '269209877',
        'reviewID': '268813607',
        'commentNum': '231',
        'reviewNum': '44',
        'perPage': '20',
        'nextPage': '2',
        }
_rq = requests.Session()
_r = requests.post(__u, data=_data, headers=__h, verify=False, timeout=30)
print _r.text
# <script>window.location.href='/'</script>
_r2 = _rq.post(__u, data=_data, headers=__h, verify=False, timeout=30)
print _r2.text
# <script>window.location.href='/'</script>
```

Thanks you very much in advance for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>window.location.href='/'</script>
```

The `'/'` for the `href` means that you need to request the root directory. Use the same domain name, but don't request a subdirectory.

Comment: Thank you. Is means i can not connect this link with parameters. But i have gave all of parameters to the do it. Did i make something wrong on this issue?

Comment: @teddy what parameters? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I means `requests`  parameters include header and data. Or i forgot some parameters to use?

Comment: @Teddy I think the only thing you have done wrong is the URL

Comment: I have tried to connect the root direction `https://www.jobui.com/` and it worked. But actually I want to do is connect other page not the root page.What can I do or try? (I have tried connect with cookies but still not worked.)

Comment: @Teddy you have to use a valid url. The one you showed in your original question just redirects to the main page. Which other page do you want to connect to?

Comment: `https://www.jobui.com/company/10954743/review/` is the website I want to crawler and the original question I post is the ajax page to load more data.